# How do I enable column sorting for three or more nested columns in React Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have built a table using React Table that has three levels of nested columns. I am trying to implement column sorting on it.

Here is an example of the data I'm using (printed from console.log() in browser):

[image]

I am trying to go off of the official example posted here for sorting table data: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/sorting?file=/src/App.js

Here is the full code for my table component in React:

```jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useTable, useFilters, useSortBy, useResizeColumns } from "react-table";
import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';
import DropdownFilter from '../DataExplorer/DropdownFilter';
import Logger from '../../../Library/Logger';

//Main table that shows the reporting metrics/dimension data 
export default function DataTable({ filterSearch, columns, data, fullData, handleFilterColumnChange, handleSelectedTableCellsChange }) {
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
        setFilter
    } = useTable({
        columns,
        data,
        defaultColumn,
        filterTypes
    },
        useFilters,
        useSortBy,
        useResizeColumns)

    // functions to run when a column is filtered depending on the type
    const filterTypes = {
        columnFilter: (rows, id, filterValue) => {
            console.log("filter values", id, filterValue);
            return rows.filter((row) => {
                const rowValue = row.values[id];
                console.log("rowValue", rowValue);
                return filterValue.includes(rowValue);
            });
        }
    };

    const CustomColumnFilter = ({
        column: { filterValue, setFilter, id, filter, Header, Type, Format, Total }
    }) => {
        console.log("filterValue", filterValue, filter, id);

        let duplicateVals = rows.map((row) => {
            return row.values[id];
        });
        const options = [...new Set(duplicateVals.values())];
        console.log("all options", options);

        if (checked[id] === undefined) {
            checked[id] = options;
        }
        console.log("options", options);
        console.log(
            "all includes",
            options.every((o) => checked[id].includes(o))
        );

        return (
            <DropdownFilter
                options={options}
                checked={checked}
                setFilter={setFilter}
                columnId={id}
                setChecked={setChecked}
                columnType={Type}
                columnName={Header}
                columnFormat={Format}
                columnTotal={Total}
            />
        );
    };

    // Set up default Filter component 
    const defaultColumn = {
        Filter: CustomColumnFilter
    };

    console.log('header groups', headerGroups);

    return (
        <div className="table-responsive" style={{ height: '400px' }}>
            <Table bordered striped hover {...getTableProps()} size="sm" style={{ height: '73%' }}>
                <thead>
                    {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                            {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                                <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())} style={column.style} className="text-capitalize">
                                    {column.render('Header')}
                                    <span>
                                        {column.isSorted
                                            ? column.isSortedDesc
                                                ? ' '
                                                : ' '
                                            : ''}
                                    </span>
                                </th>
                            ))}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </thead>
                <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()} style={{ width: '99%', overflowY: 'scroll' }}>
                    {rows.map((row) => {
                        prepareRow(row)
                        console.log("row cells", row.cells);
                        return (
                            <tr {...row.getRowProps()} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                                {row.cells.map((cell, index) => {
                                    return <td {...cell.getCellProps()} style={{ wordBreak: 'break-word', textAlign: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', }}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                                })}
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The table renders properly, but the sorting does not work. When I click a column to sort it, this error appears:

```console
4.js:153288 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortDescFirst' of undefined
    at reducer$5 (4.js:153288)
    at 4.js:151630
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at 4.js:151629
    at updateReducer (app.js?ver:22740)
    at Object.useReducer (app.js?ver:23537)
    at Object.useReducer (app.js?ver:36926)
    at useTable (4.js:151634)
    at DataTable (5.js:14320)
    at renderWithHooks (app.js?ver:22408)
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my data structure or the way I have built the component. Are there any similar examples that I can look at that would lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by removing the 'accessor' attribute from all columns EXCEPT the most deeply nested ones. This works because the table body rows are connected to the header that that are nested directly underneath.